# How to recover NTFS partition from Linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery

I've formated partition to empty - only erased information that partition is NTFS.

Partition data haven't been changed. So i think only little change to partition table is required.

How can i recover it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Comment: It successfully restored partition except boot options. Now when i try to boot the Windows it shows screen of fancy colored artefacts

Comment: To restore the bootsector, boot your PC with Win 7 installation DVD, choose "Repair your computer", choose command prompt and type in "bootsect /nt60 SYS" or "bootsect /nt60 C:/" if you have your Windows installed on C: partition. Then restart.

Comment: And if i have windows vista?

Comment: I think the procedure is the same, but the tool is called "Bootrec.exe". Try it.

Comment: You've gived me app for recovering partition. I've asked another question for that problem.